# Spring Boot. Running liquibase changelog after jpa auto-dll tables generation on hsqldb

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, liquibase

Case is like this.
I have liquibase changelog contaning only inserts.
I am trying to force Spring Boot to initialize database (hsqldb) schema using JPA based on @Entities and later execute liquibase changelog. Unfortunatelly Spring Boot is doing it in oposite order.

I checked LiquibaseAutoConfiguration and it has:

```
@AutoConfigureAfter({ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
```

so it is executed after HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration however Spring Boot still do it not the way I wish ;).

Spring Boot version: 1.3.0.RELEASE
Liquibase-core version: 3.5.1

Thank you in advance for any naswer

Answer (score 12):

Possible solution is to disable automatic boot liquibase run via `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
liquibase.enabled=false
```

and then manually configure `SpringLiquibase` bean to depends on `entityManagerFactory`:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties() {
        return new LiquibaseProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "entityManagerFactory")
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties = liquibaseProperties();
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(liquibaseProperties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDataSource(getDataSource(liquibaseProperties));
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
        liquibase.setLabels(liquibaseProperties.getLabels());
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseProperties.getParameters());
        return liquibase;
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource(LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
        if (liquibaseProperties.getUrl() == null) {
            return this.dataSource;
        }
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(liquibaseProperties.getUrl())
            .username(liquibaseProperties.getUser())
            .password(liquibaseProperties.getPassword()).build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

However I'd strongly encourage to use liquibase to build schema as well. I believe it was designed (see `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseJpaDependencyConfiguration`) to run before hibernate's `ddl-auto` so that it's possible to set `ddl-auto=validate` and have liquibase schema validated by hibernate.

Comment: My case is exactly opposite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918808/execute-liquibase-before-hibernate-in-springboot-using-springjpa

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in (...) : Circular depends-on relationship between 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by Radek Postołowicz served me quite some time but didn't work anymore after updating to spring-boot 2.5.0. I think it can be fully replaced by adding the following property to `application.properties` (or yml):

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

This is also mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql).

Comment: Using this property with Spring Boot 3 (3.0.4) I got a circular depends on relationship error :/

Answer (score 1):

You should use Liquibase for DDL statements too. It doesn't make sense to use it solely for DML statements and then use another solution for DDL. Liquibase is equally well suited for either. And Liquibase is especially well-suited for the case where you develop on one type of database and deploy to another. In fact Liquibase is database engine agnostic.

If you need to execute some SQL ***before*** Liquibase fires (like creating the schema where Liquibase itself lives) then you can use [Pre-Liquibase](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase), but that should only be for whatever it is that absolutely cannot be in Liquibase changelogs.

All in all: I would advice against using all of the following:

- JPA ddl (meaning the `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` settings)
- Hibernate ddl (meaning the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` setting)
- DataSource initialization (meaning the `spring.sql.init.mode` setting)

when using Spring Boot and Liquibase. The above methods are not guaranteed to fire before Liquibase. When you have Liquibase you don't need any of the above methods.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Spring Boot to 2.5.3 and have the same problem.
I solved the issue by using a class `CustomSpringLiquibase` (Kotlin version) :

```
class CustomSpringLiquibase(
        private var springLiquibase: SpringLiquibase
) : InitializingBean, BeanNameAware, ResourceLoaderAware {

    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSpringLiquibase::class.java)
    }

    @Throws(LiquibaseException::class)
    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        LOGGER.info("Init Liquibase")
        springLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet()
    }

    override fun setBeanName(name: String) {
        springLiquibase.beanName = name
    }

    override fun setResourceLoader(resourceLoader: ResourceLoader) {
        springLiquibase.resourceLoader = resourceLoader
    }
}
```

And in my `SpringBootApplication` class I added the following (Java Version):

```
@Bean
@DependsOn(value = "entityManagerFactory")
public CustomSpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties = liquibaseProperties();
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    ....
    return new CustomSpringLiquibase(liquibase);
}
```