# Spring Boot: start liquibase changes only once Tomcat started

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, liquibase

Right now, my Liquibase scripts are integrated in my product (a Spring boot application). I would like to know if there is an easy way to postpone the Liquibase changes once Tomcat has finished to start from a Spring Boot application?

Or if need to separate Liquibase changes from the Spring Boot app to run this behavior?

Comment: If you want to run Liquibase after something was done, maybe you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240366/spring-boot-running-liquibase-changelog-after-jpa-auto-dll-tables-generation-on

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked previously. It has several answers, but I'll summarize the most popular below.: [Spring Boot. Running liquibase changelog after JPA auto-dll tables generation on hsqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240366/spring-boot-running-liquibase-changelog-after-jpa-auto-dll-tables-generation-on)

*Answer posted by Radek Postołowicz*

> Possible solution is to disable automatic boot liquibase run via `application.properties:`
>
> ```
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
> liquibase.enabled=false
> ```
>
> and then manually configure SpringLiquibase bean to depend on `entityManagerFactory:`
>
> ```
> import javax.sql.DataSource;
>
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
> import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
> import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
>
> import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
>
> @SpringBootApplication
> public class DemoApplication {
>
>     @Autowired
>     private DataSource dataSource;
>
>     @Bean
>     public LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties() {
>         return new LiquibaseProperties();
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     @DependsOn(value = "entityManagerFactory")
>     public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
>         LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties = liquibaseProperties();
>         SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
>         liquibase.setChangeLog(liquibaseProperties.getChangeLog());
>         liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
>         liquibase.setDataSource(getDataSource(liquibaseProperties));
>         liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
>         liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
>         liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
>         liquibase.setLabels(liquibaseProperties.getLabels());
>         liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseProperties.getParameters());
>         return liquibase;
>     }
>
>     private DataSource getDataSource(LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
>         if (liquibaseProperties.getUrl() == null) {
>             return this.dataSource;
>         }
>         return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(liquibaseProperties.getUrl())
>             .username(liquibaseProperties.getUser())
>              .password(liquibaseProperties.getPassword()).build();
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> However I'd strongly encourage to use liquibase to build schema as well. I believe it was designed (see org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseJpaDependencyConfiguration) to run before hibernate's ddl-auto so that it's possible to set ddl-auto=validate and have liquibase schema validated by hibernate.